# Two direcories.. Two capacities.. One drive.. How to fix this?

Tags: partitioning, debugging, media, rm, mkdir

[image]

This is my predicament You see here one drive (the Intel SSD shown on disks app) which is labeled as /device/sdb

yet some how an other drive (WD HDD) labeled as /device/sdc link to the same directory as SDB only that SDB has a "1" next to the name (as shown on lsblk)

On the left side you see two internal drives both called DATA and DATA when you hover the mouse on them (not DATA and DATA1)

Both have the same folders and same files (I checked all files and video are executable and present in both windows)

Yet one "data" disk has 12GB more space than the other "data" disk!!!

And this is supposed to be the same disk!!!

I am not sure how this is happened..

All I want to know is how to fix it.

Thank you.

P.S extra question.. what are those "loop devices"  ? never saw them again in my life and dont know what created them either.

df -h output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G   10M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       101G  6,2G   90G   7% /
tmpfs           7,9G  1,2M  7,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,9G     0  7,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       77M   77M     0 100% /snap/core/714
/dev/loop1      256K  256K     0 100% /snap/htop/68
/dev/sda1       511M  3,6M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1,6G  136K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdc1       459G   80G  356G  19% /media/papajo/DATA
/dev/sdb        448G   80G  368G  18% /media/papajo/DATA1
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: Ιτ was too complex for me to describe the issue along with the technical details in a sensible way via text

Comment: You are posting a screenshot of a terminal. You can post that output as text. As for the other screenshots, use `sudo parted -l` or `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: again copy pasting text that has identical or almost identical directories and showing different capacities might be more confusing than clarifying besides that why is there a picture button if it was not allowed to post pictures I think a messed up situation such as the above is a perfect example on why to post a screenshot rather than text. If you know something about the issue then please help me out.

Comment: Could you please add the output of 'df -h' ?

Comment: I edit the post to add the output... again here the strange thing with the capacity while being the same disk!!!!

Comment: OMG turns out that the difference in the capacity is because IT DESTROYED my windows hard disc (SDC...) it dublicated all the files that are on my data disk (SDB) and also its name!!! now SDC instead of being an 80% full disk with windows and filres is a 19% full ext4 disc with corrupted data and the files I already have on DATA (which on the terminal appears as DATA1 for some reason lol) I dont know if I should cry or laugh...